# CSS transition not work

Tags: css, css-transitions

this is my code:

```css
.pic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px white solid;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #E0DDDD;
  transition: 1s;
}
.pic img:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
.pic img {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="./core/image.php?userid=1&amp;dateline=1356257261" alt="VBpro" title="VBpro">
</div>
```

why is the transition not working in my code and what can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: What is supposed to transition?

Comment: You're using shorthand syntax, but only specifying one argument (the `transition-duration`, probably).

Comment: not work bro.i know problem.when i set a size insted of 100% transition work perfect but when use 100% not work.No solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code:

- **You haven't defined what you want to transition**. You've just said `transition:1s;`, which tells the browser... nothing. If you want to, say, change the opacity of the image, you would write `transition:opacity 1s;`.
- **Put the transition code on the element where the transition won't run**. Then, just change the property that you want to transition and the browser will do the rest.

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q3nj9n54/

Also, please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

**EDIT:**

@ali-b Now that I know what you want to transition between (width and height), it should be easier to make this work.

- To animate multiple properties, you need to comma seperate them in the `transition` property.
- Also, at the moment, the width and height properties that you have defined are on the `.pic` element, **not** the image - it is essential that the values you want to animate are on the right property :P
- On that note, you'll want `.pic` to be **bigger** than 150px by 150px, as otherwise there will be no change in the transition - the image will already be at 100% by 100%.
- You **still** need to put the transition code onto the image **before** it's hovered - on hover, you just need to change the width and height.

Here's another fiddle of the transition between of width and height: https://jsfiddle.net/2j423dn5/

**EDIT:**

Now I get what you want :D

I was animating the wrong element.

This'll solve your problems: https://jsfiddle.net/2j423dn5/2/

Comment: .i know problem.when i set a size insted of 100% transition work perfect but when use 100% not work.No solution?

Comment: @Stewartside Well, that's something I didn't know. Browser support is coming along better than I thought :D

Comment: Yep, thankfully IE has supported transitions pretty well and all other browsers have for a very long time.

Comment: I think you do not understand my problem.i want in hover change img size to natural size

Comment: OK. Well, the browser doesn't know that because you haven't defined that in your `transition`. You'll have to do `transition:width 1s ease-in-out, height 1s ease-in-out;` if you want animate both the width and the height at the same time.

Comment: @ali-b Read by latest edit... should fix your problem.

Comment: my problem it is that pic img is not a fixed size and user can upload any size pic.i  cant write a aixed size for "pic img" class.

Comment: @ali-b Well, why didn't you say so from the start? :P

Comment: @ali-b Oh, I understand what you want. Ignore my latest edit, I thought you were trying to do something way different :P

Comment: the box must be fixed 150px*150px . and only pic size must in hover be natural size.

Answer (score 1):

Your `transition` code was a little off and needed some amendments.

I wasn't too sure what you're trying to add the actual transition to so i added code to do it on either the `img` or on its container so you have some options.

The `transition` CSS attribute is all of the `transition` attributes such as duration, attributes and style.

I also do not believe that Toastrackenigma's answer is wholly true as CSS Transitions don't require any browser prefixes ([See here on CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions))

Ultimately, its just a little bit of incorrect syntax and a missing part on the transition telling it what elements it needs to run on.

```css
.pic {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px white solid;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #E0DDDD;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}
.pic.on_pic:hover {
  border: 2px red solid;
}
.pic.on_img img:hover {
  border: 2px red solid;
}
.pic.to_size:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic on_pic">
  <img src="./core/image.php?userid=1&amp;dateline=1356257261" alt="VBpro" title="VBpro">
</div>

<div class="pic on_img">
  <img src="./core/image.php?userid=1&amp;dateline=1356257261" alt="VBpro" title="VBpro">
</div>

<div class="pic to_size">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/city/" alt="VBpro" title="VBpro">
</div>
```

In the comments below is the final fixed problem for the OP but here it is for other people without having to trawl through lots of comments.

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ung5az2L/1/)

Comment: I think an explanation would be nice ;)

Comment: And the explanation, so that people can understand what you changed, why you changed it and how the change makes it work?

Comment: Apologies guys, Explanation added to why theres 2 variants and gonna add some more in a second to it. Just pressed submit a little too quick :P

Comment: I think you do not understand my problem.i want in hover change img size to natural size

Comment: @ali.b could you possibly explain it a bit better then? From what I gathered your transition was not working and now your transition does work in my answer with some amended CSS.

Comment: @ali.b Ive added a 3rd part to my code which resizes the image to its original size of 300x300px and it should fit your requirements.

Comment: @ali.b https://jsfiddle.net/ung5az2L/1/ the hover event is on the wrong element. see https://jsfiddle.net/ung5az2L/1/ for a final fix.